# What is a word that captures the *desire* to empathize?

Tags: single-word-requests

[I've checked all the [single-word-requests about empathy](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=%5bsingle-word-requests%5d%20empathy%20is%3aq); they mostly deal with those who lack empathy or somehow empathize "wrongly."]

Empathy is (roughly) the *ability* to understand another's experience, to put oneself in another's shoes.

Is there a word that captures the *desire* to empathize? Or the enjoyment thereof or satisfaction derived therefrom?

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I guess it would be "$word is a traiit we aim to cultivate at $awesome_place: not only the *ability* to empathize, but also the impulse to do so." It's almost like the other end of the connection from *pathos*. If *pathos* is trying to draw out a connection to oneself from another, this would be the desire to extend a connection from oneself to another. (In all transparency, I'm trying to modify a syllabus where, for years, I've claimed that empathy is a valued trait. I'm realizing, though, that's not *quite* it, there's a bit more I'd like to capture.)

Comment: May be you are looking for **compassionate empathy.**

Answer (score 1):

*Solicitude* is the nearest I can think of.

> **Solicitude:** the quality of caring about other people's comfort, safety, and how they feel.
>
> Example: I'm touched by your solicitude.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/solicitude)

As a quality of another quality, it may fit your question.